# Coldfusion Query of Query missing results from date BETWEEN clause

Tags: sql, date, coldfusion, between

I have a query called AllPosts from a query of a query.

AllPosts has two results:

```
Row 1| ID: 2   PublishedDate: 2012-05-30 16:47:00.0
Row 2| ID: 3   PublishedDate: 2012-05-31 15:50:00.0
```

When I do a query of a query on AllPosts called FilterPosts using

```
WHERE PublishedDate BETWEEN '2012-05-01 00:00:00' AND '2012-05-31 23:59:00'
```

(Note that the actual query is doing cfqueryparam cf_sql_date for these values)

I expect FilterPosts to have the same rows as AllPosts, instead I only get ID 2. If I change ID 2's published date to `2012-05-30 23:59:50.0`, FilterPosts returns the correct results.

I have also tried

```
WHERE PublishedDate >= '2012-05-01 00:00:00'   
AND   PublishedDate <= '2012-05-31 23:59:00'
```

There is something specifically odd with May 31st.

I'm pulling my hair out here! Thanks!

I tried scratch building a the original query, and oddly enough, same results!

```
<cfset test = queryNew("Name,PublishedDate", "VarChar, Time" )>
<cfset queryAddRow(test)>    
<cfset querySetCell(test,"PublishedDate","2012-05-30 16:47:00.0")>     
<cfset querySetCell(test,"Name","First Entry")>    
<cfset queryAddRow(test)>    
<cfset querySetCell(test,"PublishedDate","2012-05-31 15:47:00.0")>    
<cfset querySetCell(test,"Name","Second Entry")>    

<cfset StartDate = CreateDate(2012, 5, 1)>

<cfquery name="filter" dbtype="query">    
    SELECT Name, PublishedDate    
    FROM    test
WHERE    1=1
AND PublishedDate >= <cfqueryparam value="#StartDate#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_date">
AND PublishedDate <= <cfqueryparam value="#DateAdd( 'n', -1, DateAdd('m', 1, StartDate) )#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_date">
 </cfquery>
```

The results of Filter only has 'FirstEntry' rather than both like it should.

Comment: Despite putting 4 spaces in front of all my code lines, it wouldn't hold formatting. What did you do different!? Thanks for editing!

Comment: You need a blank line either side too - you had blanks after but not before.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Oddly enough it had to do with cfqueryparam. I had been using CreateDate() to create my start/end dates like this:

```
<cfset StartDate = CreateDate(2012,5, 1)>
```

I was using it in my SQL WHERE in the query of query like this:

```
WHERE PublishedDate >=  <cfqueryparam value="#StartDate#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_date">
```

It was `cf_sql_date`. It should be `cf_sql_timestamp` The date was capping it to 5-31, and thus anything posted later on in the day on 5-31 was omitted. The minutes were dropping.

Thanks for everyone's input.

Fixing legacy code rocks!

Comment: Glad you got it fixed, that was the same thing I was getting at to add the one day to the end to get 6-1 at 00:00 time stamp.

Comment: +1 to Turnkey's suggestion. By using `Col < #dayAfterEndDate#` you do not have to worry about time portion issues like this. I use it frequently and it works very well.

Answer (score 3):

You didn't say which database you're using but if it's ODBC or MSSQL I usually do something like this:

```
WHERE PublishedDate >= '2012-05-01'
AND PublishedDate < '2012-06-01'
```

Basically you add one day to the end date that you want to include and use the less than operator.  Leaving off the times prevents any oddities with how the date is internally constructed.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The original source database is MS SQL but it's specifically the Query of a Query issue. The original, AllPosts has the correct data (it also happens to be query of a query). FilteredPosts. I'm using CreateDate to get the star/end dates. It seems to add in the seconds on its own.

Comment: I tend to avoid Q of Q because of similar oddities I've seen in the past, but understand why you might want them to save the second trip to the DB.  Did it still fail if you use the simple date as suggested?

Comment: ie in dynamic terms try: `PublishedDate < <cfqueryparam value="#DateAdd('m', 1, StartDate)#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_date">`. It should work fine.

Answer (score 1):

Try comparing by removing the `timepart` from datetime. So your `between` should look like

```
WHERE PublishedDate BETWEEN '2012-05-01' AND '2012-05-31'
```

Comment: That is okay for the starting date, but will still drop the May 31 record because it is like saying: `PublishedDate >= '2012-05-01 00:00:00.0' AND  PublishedDate <= '2012-05-31 00:00:00.0'`

Comment: @Leigh, in that cased we need to change the upper limit to `2012-06-01` instead of `2012-05-31`.

Comment: Yeah, but `BEWTWEEN` is typically inclusive, meaning it would also pick up records stamped exactly '2012-06-01 00:00:00.0'. So unlike Turnkey's approach, there is still a small chance of picking up unwanted records.

Comment: @Leigh, true and that's what `between` does right? inclusive of the upper and lower limit. I went with `BETWEEN` cause OP was asking for same.

Comment: Yeah, but I think he wanted all records *dated* anytime in the month of May 2012. The difference is your query would include records dated June 1st at midnight, while Turnkey's would not (because of the `<`). So there is a slight difference in the results. In other words, your query says include June 1st at midnight, his says exclude it.

Comment: Re: *I went with BETWEEN cause OP was asking for same* True, and it can be done with `BETWEEN`. But you then you must worry about constructing exactly the right number of minutes, seconds, ecetera or risk dropping records ie `BETWEEN start AND 2012-05-31 23:59:59.999`. IMO it is much simpler to just use `<`.